# Expressjs higher order router vs appending to request

Tags: node.js, express, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Let's say I want to pass to an ExpressJS route callback an object.

I know I can append to `app`:

```js
// router.js
const getFoo = (req, res) => res.json(req.app.foo);

// index.js
const app = express();
app.foo = {};
app.get('/foo', getFoo);
```

or I can use a higher order function:

```js
// router.js
const getFoo = foo => (req, res) => res.json(foo);

// index.js
const app = express();
const foo = {};
app.get('/foo', getFoo(foo));
```

Both are easy to write, extend and test.
But, I don't know the implications of the solutions and whether one is better.

Is there anyone knowing real differences between the two approaches?

Answer (score 3):

I think the second solution is more correct, here's why.

imagine you get used to the first solution and one day you need to send something called `post` or `get` or anything with the name of `app` property and you forget that there is already a property named like that, so you override original property without even realizing and when you call `app.post()` program will crash.

Believe me, you don't want hours of research wasted on something like that and realizing that you simply overrode original method

Also, in my opinion, it's always a bad idea mutating original object which wasn't generated by you

Answer (score 0):

As @vahe-yavrumian mentioned it is not a good idea to mutate the state of the object created by a third party library.

between you can also use `app.get()` and `app.set()` methods to pass any data to the other routers in the queue (seems those methods are there just for this purpose.)

more information at https://expressjs.com/en/api.html.

Answer (score 0):

The second solution easily allows you to pass different value for `foo` on different routes, if you ever found a need to do that.

The first solution essentially puts the value on the `app` singleton, which has all the implications of using singletons. (And as mentioned by @Anees, for *express* specifically the `app` settings with [`get`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get) and [`set`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.set) are the proper place to store this, not a custom property)